# fetch all details of instance thru aws cli from all regions in proper format csv file

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need details thru CLI from all regions. I've tried below script, but not able to fetch all details. I need the following fields:

- Instances name
- Instances status
- Virtualization
- AWS Region
- Instances Type
- DNS Host Name
- Applications name
- Account ID

Here is my script:

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3`; do
  echo -e "\nListing Instances in region:'$region'..."
  aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region | jq -R '.Reservations[] | ( .Instances[] | {state: .State.Name, name: .KeyName, type: .InstanceType, key: .KeyName})' aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,Tags[]]' --output text
done
```

Comment: Review the Output section at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html and try to find all of the outputs that you need (e.g. InstanceType). For anything you cannot find, update your question with that info.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some help to you, I'm the founder of [CloudRanger](http://go.cloudranger.com/l/211332/2017-05-22/477sk8) and we had a similar problem to get all instance types in all regions, which was not available. So we have provided a free service where we maintain a JSON list of all available instance types by region, some sample code in the github repo that should how you can use it.

[github.com/cloud-ranger/CRITAS](http://go.cloudranger.com/l/211332/2017-05-22/477sk6)

Hope it helps.

Dave

Comment: I tired below script and its working for me       .for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3`
do
     echo -e "\nListing Instances in region:'$region'..."
     aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0],Tags[?Key==`Applications`].Value[] | [0], State.Name,VirtualizationType,InstanceType,PublicDnsName,Placement.AvailabilityZone,OwnerId]'
done